# Can I use a confirm() prompt inside a function? How?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, confirm

How do I cause the cancel button to not process the save on the page.

I am trying to only initiate the prompt when element id 'item' is changed.

I get the OK and CANCEL prompt very well indeed, but cancel does not stop the page from submitting.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var strProductNum = document.getElementById('item').value;
function isProductNumChanged(itemValue){
    if (strProductNum != itemValue){
        var valueYesNo = confirm('Really change this Product Number to ' + document.getElementById('item').value + '?');
    }
    if (valueYesNo){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

This is how I fire the event:

```
<h:commandButton id="save1"
                onclick="isProductNumChanged(document.getElementById('item').value);"
                value="Save" action="#{itemHome.saveItem}" />
```

Comment: Can you show us how you set this function to run when the form is submitted (e.g. `<form onSubmit="isProductNumChanged">` or what?

Comment: Your function doesn't have anything to do with the form submit, so until the two are wired together, you're not going to prevent a save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using inline event handlers (like `onclick=""`) and you need to stop the default event happening, it is not enough to return false from your event handler function. You also have to put `return` before the name of the function when you specify the inline event handler.

```
 onclick="return isProductNumChanged(document.getElementById('item').value);"
```

Comment: @Caspar OP added it later. I was waiting for that line to be added, because the function should have been working based on the problem description, so I suspected it must be the inline handler. Thanks for the upvote.